# 'View more' link in php page for every 100 posts shown from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have a PHP page which pulls the data from the DB table and echo's out. but when the table columns are like 1000 to 5000 and more, the page loading gets too slow that it takes minutes.

I m trying to add a view more link at the bottom of the page where for every 100 posts the view more link appears to view another 100 posts once clicked.

**And I'm aware of pagination which I don't want to adopt for some reasons..**

Hope I m clear on explaining my situation.

My code so far goes as:

```
   <html>
<head>
<?php include('db.php'); ?>

</head>
<body>

<?php 
$page = 0;

if(isset($_GET["Page"])){
   $page = $_GET["Page"];
}
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM smf_log_digest WHERE note_type = 'topic' ORDER BY id_msg DESC";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $number = $row2["id_msg"];
?>
<?php 
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number AND id_board = 4 LIMIT 100 OFFSET " . $page * 100;
    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
    if ($result3->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $member = $row3["id_member"];
        $replies = $row3["id_topic"];
?>
<script>
var page = 0;

function GetData(){
    page++;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "/getData?page="+page, true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             <?php echo substr($row3['body'], 0, 150); ?>
        }
    }
}
</script>


<?php     }
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
?>
<?php     }
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
?>
<div onclick="GetData()">Show More</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I mentioned the query works fine pulling all the data from the table, but I would like to limit it to 100 and give a "view more" button at the bottom of every 100 posts showed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use the keyword “pagination”, you should be able to find more than enough explanations of the principle. If you don’t want to go to different “pages” of results, but append the new entries under the existing ones in the current page, then throw AJAX into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to include a "page" counter which will work as a number of clicks on 'show more' to calculate offset for the query.

```
$page = 0;

if(isset($_GET["Page"])){
   $page = $_GET["Page"];
}

"SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number AND id_board = 4 LIMIT 100 OFFSET " . $page * 100;
```

Now, JavaScript, make a request to your php page, I called it 'getData' and include Get parameters with the counter.

```
var page = 0;

function GetData(){
    page++;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "/getData?page="+page, true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // Append the results here.
        }
    }
}
```

You want to run this function on each click on the DOM.

```
<div onclick="GetData()">Show More</div>
```

Note, this is a sample, you will need to do some modifications to suit your purpose. As you didn't provide any html, it is impossible for one to write full code and I'm not fancying writing the whole thing (HTML etc) for you :), so there you go.

Edit: The Ajax call along with appending results could be simplified by using JQuery, however as you tagged it as just JavaScript I provided a solution without it.

Edit:

Put your PHP code to a new file called getData.php for example and leave it on root (for example purpose)

```
<?php 
$page = 0;

if(isset($_GET["Page"])){
   $page = $_GET["Page"];
}
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM smf_log_digest WHERE note_type = 'topic' ORDER BY id_msg DESC";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $number = $row2["id_msg"];
    }
    }

    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number AND id_board = 4 LIMIT 100 OFFSET " . $page * 100;
    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
    if ($result3->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $member = $row3["id_member"];
        $replies = $row3["id_topic"];
       }
    }
?>
```

Modify your Ajax request, the URL will now become "/getData.php?page="+page,

Now once you obtain the returned data, you can append it.

Take a look at this function

```
function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        // Append the results here.
    }
}
```

You can append to body using `document.body.innerHTML +=`

So your final function will now become

```
function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.body.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

I have added closing brackets to your php file to close the while loop and if statements.
If you don't want to use brackets you need to make sure you never opened them to avoid syntax errors, if you do not put the brackets in however only the next line will correspond to the loop/if statement, in case you're not aware.

Happy learning.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. and I tried your method, but it seems like I missed something.. please check on the updated question. thanks.. awaiting your reply.

Comment: @HarishKolliparat Yes you missed appending the data to the page itself... Look at the comment "// Append the results here.". You also need to separate your php into separate file or you'll be appending the whole HTML document into the document. You didn't even change the Ajax url. As I said I won't spoon-feed you the complete code, make some effort. You have to make little changes already.

Comment: I apologize for bothering you, basically, i m a chemical eng. and this is kinda some personal interest. Please take a look at the updated question. so far that's what I understood.  once again thanks for your time.

Comment: @HarishKolliparat the answer is correct, but you have to use JavaScript to append the results. PHP runs on your server when your page loads, you need client-side code to process AJAX results.

Comment: @HarishKolliparat See my edit. I have included additional information how to integrate 'dynamic' loading of content.

Comment: @Adriani6 I didn't get one thing like we haven't included the echo row3 part to print out the data.. how would it print?

Comment: @HarishKolliparat Apologies if I sound rude, but I think I have provided you with enough code and information for yourself to figure out where to add the echo considering you have written some code already, this shouldn't be a difficult task. If I provide you with absolutely everything you won't learn, you'll just copy & paste.